# is there a way to prove the Mean-value formulas using complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

> **THEOREM :** $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$ and suppose $u \in C^2(U) $ is harmonic within $U$, then :
>   $$u(x)= \def\avint{\mathop{\,\rlap{-}\!\!\int}\nolimits} \avint_{B(x,r)}u\,dy = \def\avint{\mathop{\,\rlap{-}\!\!\int}\nolimits} \avint_{\partial B(x,r)}u\,dS$$
>   for each ball $B(x,r) \subset U$

there's a nice proof in Evan's PDE book which only involves real analysis. since harmonic functions can be implicitly identified as the real or imagniary part of holomorphic functions, how does one prove or atleast reformulate this theorem using complex analysis notions ?

any comment, references will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know that harmonic functions in $\Bbb R^2 \simeq \Bbb C$ are locally the real parts of holomorphic functions. Is that true for arbitrary dimensions? What would be a holomorphic function in $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: If $n=2$ and $u$ is given, can you proceed by finding $f$ with $f=u+iv$, write down the Cauchy integral formula for $f$, and then split into $f$ in integrand as $f=u+iv$?. When $n=2k$ is even, then $R^n$ = $C^k$, and maybe you can do the same thing.

Comment: @MartinR good point, I've heard of Several complex variables calculus. perhaps if I take a look into that I'll find an answer.

Comment: To follow up to my comment, check out Section 10.1 of Ullrich's book Complex Made Simple.

Comment: @LucasSilva I know how to find a harmonic conjugate. and since $f$ would be analytic the integral is zero and $2\pi$ is indeed the measure of the unit ball and since the integral is zero for every closed, connected and smooth contour. then picking the bounday of the unit ball we get the mean value formula but only for the unit ball. how do you generalize it to any ball though ? and thanks for the reference btw.

Comment: @rapidracim Does it not work if you pick the boundary of the ball $B(x,r)$ as the contour? Also, I was thinking of the Cauchy integral formula ($f(a) = (2 \pi i)^{-1} \int_{\gamma} f(z)/(z-a)dz$), not the Cauchy theorem ($\int_{\gamma} f dz = 0$). But since the formula can be proved from the theorem, I guess it doesn't matter.

Comment: As another reference, you can look at Chapter 11 of Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis. Rudin also gets the harmonic mean value theorem by the complex analysis route. Indeed, Ullrich's book is largely inspired by Rudin's treatment, as you can read in the preface.

Answer (score 8):

For $n=2$ one can proceed as follows (this is essentially an elaboration
of above comments):

If $u$ is harmonic in $ U \subset \Bbb C$ and $B(z_0, R) \subset U$ then
$u = \operatorname{Re} f$ for some holomorphic function $f$ in $B(z_0, R)$.
This is true in any simply-connected domain in $\Bbb C$, $f$ can for
example be chosen as an anti-derivative of the (holomorphic) function
$u_x - i u_y$.

The Cauchy integral formula then states that for $0 < r < R$ and the path
$\gamma(t) = z_0 + re^{it}$, $0 \le t \le 2 \pi$,
$$
 f(z_0) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z_0} \, d\zeta = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} f(z_0 + re^{it}) \, dt \, .
$$

Taking real parts gives the mean-value formula for $u$:
$$
 u(z_0) =  \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} u(z_0 + re^{it}) \, dt \, .
$$

Finally, the “area form” of the mean-value formula follows by integration
over the radius:
$$
 \frac{1}{\pi r^2} \int_{B(z_0, r)} u(x, y)\, dx dy =
 \frac{1}{\pi r^2} \int_0^r \int_0^{2 \pi}  u(z_0 + \rho e^{it})
 \rho \, dt \, d\rho = \frac{1}{\pi r^2} \int_0^r 2 \pi u(z_0) \rho \, d\rho = u(z_0) \, .
$$